# Typesafe prototype patching

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

Say I have the following interface in module `src/Container`

```
export abstract class Container<T> implements Iterable<T> {
  public abstract [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>
}
```

Now I want to extend this class from another file `src/extensions/transformSomething`

```
import { Container } from '../Container'
declare module '../Enumerable' {
  interface Container<T> {
    transformSomething<TOut>(this: Container<T>, selector: (x : T) => TOut) : Container<TOut>
  }
}
```

then I define an implementation of this extension function

```
function transformSomething<T, TOut>(
  this: Container<T>,
  selector: (x : T) => TOut
): Container<TOut> {
  //...
  const returnValue:SomeContainerType<TOut> = //...
  return returnValue
}
```

I can now attach this to the `Container<T>` as easy as

```
Container.prototype.transformSomething = transformSomething
```

Winning.

Now, say I already have an implementation in a different, more functional, less prototypical representation that follows the form:

```
(...args: any[]) => (src: any) => any
```

for instance:

```
export const transformSomethingF = <T, TOut>(selector: (x : T) => TOut) => (src: Container<T>): Container<TOut> => {
    //...
    const returnValue:SomeContainerType<TOut> = //...
    return returnValue
}
```

I can write a method that converts this into a `this`-based function:

```
export const convertForPrototype =
  <TIn, TOut, U extends any[], T extends (...args: U) => (src: TIn) => TOut>
    (func: T): (this: TIn, ...args: U) => TOut => {
    return function (this: TIn, ...args: U) {
      return func(...args)(this);
    };
  };
```

and now, converting our `transformSomethingF` into a function that works in the prototype is as easy as:

```
Enumerable.prototype.select = convertForPrototype(select)
```

So, can we do the same with the interface extension above? Can we change

```
import { Container } from '../Container'
declare module '../Enumerable' {
  interface Container<T> {
    transformSomething<TOut>(this: Container<T>, selector: (x : T) => TOut) : Container<TOut>
  }
}
```

into

```
import { Container } from '../Container'
declare module '../Enumerable' {
  interface Container<T> {
    transformSomething: PrototypeRepresentation<typeof transformSomethingF>
  }
}
```

???

We might do this by defining the following type:

```
export type PrototypeRepresentation<TSrc,T extends (...args: any[]) => (src: any) => any> =
    T extends (...args: infer P) => (src: TSrc) => infer TOut ?
    (this: TSrc, ...arg: P) => TOut : never;
```

but when I try this, attempting to actually use `Container.transformSomething`

```
const someContainer : Container<number> = //...
const result = someContainer.transformSomething(x => x * 2)
```

I see the following issue:

> (parameter) x: any
>
> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'never' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)
>
> Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You get `any` because the types are recursive in a  way TS can't cope with (it should have errored IMO but default to any instead). Also transforming functions with generics is not something we can do. We just recently got improvements to forward generic type arguments for `pipe` like functions, but these are very limited in scope and have not made their way to conditional types in any way

Comment: Thanks @TitianCernicova-Dragomir . You might have guessed that I'm implementing support for a `pipe`-like operator myself, hence the `(...args: any[]) => (src: any) => any` functions in the first place. I was hoping that I might draw you in. You're completely bossing the typescript tag :). Good work. Back to the drawing board for me.

Comment: If you want to run any TS ideas by me I'm available on gitter, always looking for fun TS type issues :)